# Print array with pointer in C

Tags: c, dynamic, printf, allocation

I have a pointer to an array of `char` and I need to print the entire array (not one after the other but the entire array). I have the error: `zsh: segmentation fault`. I don't understand why.
My code take a text from `stdin` and put the chars in an array. If the first array `char_array` isn't big enough I put them in the second one called `bigger_array`.

```
int main() {
    int c;
    int index = 0;
    size_t size = 100;                        
    char *char_array = malloc(size * sizeof(char)); 
    if (char_array != 0) {
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && index < size) {
            char_array[index] = c;
            index++;
        }
        size_t newSize = size * 100;
        char *bigger_array = realloc(char_array, newSize * sizeof(char)); 
        if (bigger_array != 0) {
            bigger_array = char_array;
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && index < newSize) {
                bigger_array[index] = c;
                index++;
            }
            size = newSize;
        }
    }
    printf(*char_array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using `bigger_array` even when the first array had enough elements for the input.

Comment: Trying to print what is pointed at by `char_array` when `char_array == 0` is bad.

Comment: When printing out a array your best bet is to use a loop, but you need to look over your code, what is it you want to check with char_array != 0, if you reallocate memory to a new char pointer why do you then have bigger_array = char_array?. Also you are not taking a file from stdin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- you do not include `<stdio.h>` nor `<stdlib.h>`
- you should free `char_array` and store `big_array` to `char_array` so `char_array` points to the bigger allocated array.
- `printf(*char_array)` has undefined behavior for multiple reasons. You can print the characters with `fwrite(char_array, 1, index, stdout)` or with `printf("%.*s\n", (int)index, char_array)`.
- there is no need for separate loops, just reallocate the array on demand.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    size_t index = 0;
    size_t size = 100;
    char *char_array = malloc(size);
    if (char_array != NULL) {
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
            if (index == size) {
                size_t new_size = size + size / 2 + size / 8; /* increase by the golden ratio */
                char *new_array = realloc(char_array, new_size);
                if (new_array == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
                    free(char_array);
                    return 1;
                }
                size = new_size;
                char_array = new_array;
            }
            char_array[index++] = c;
        }
        printf("%.*s\n", (int)index, char_array);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- `bigger_array = char_array;` should be `char_array = bigger_array;`. Otherwise, the pointer to newly allocated buffer is overwritten to the pointer to old buffer and bad thing will happen.
- `printf(*char_array);` is bad because it is passing a integer (one character) where pointer is required. It should be `printf("%.*s", index, char_array);`. Note that the length to print is specified and you don't need to add terminating null-character thanks to that.

Answer (score 0):

Considere this as a comment ^^

I advise you to use flags for **warning** with your complier. for exemple for `gcc` flags `-W -Wextra -Wshadow` are good to use and prevent lost of time.